# OperationalError: no such table: authsys_user_user_permissions

Tags: python, django, sqlite3

ребята, у меня неполадки в базе данных sqlite3 в django, и код уже загружен на pythonanywhere можно ли так удалить базу, исправить ее и обратно закинуть? Возможно ли это, если нет есть ли другие варианты???

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас есть доступ - для начала лучше остановить http демон. (Например, в случае apache на linux - в командной строке *service apache2 stop*)

Если старая база не нужна, то смотрим  в файл settings.py, ищем запись типа

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
```

в поле **NAME** указан путь к базе данных.

Удаляете файл, к которому указан путь.

Далее в shell:

```
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Вводите логин, почту и пароль суперпользователя.
Снова запускаете http демон ( *service apache2 start*)
Пользуетесь.

З.Ы.:
Если старая база всё таки нужна - можно попробывать ее восстановить с помощью ПО типа SQLite Expert и подобного просто скачав файл с сервера (предварительно обязательно остановив демон)